# Play Application behind apache Proxy with sub-uri not working

Tags: apache, playframework, proxy

I'm having some trouble deploying my Play 2.3 application behind an Apache Reverse Proxy. In this particular case, the application has to be accessed under a sub-uri and via SSL. To be short, here is what i'm trying to do:

- Use Apache 2.2 as Reverse Proxy and SSL-Endpoint for the application (The connection between Apache and Play is not using SSL)
- Run the application under a sub-uri called "/playtool"

For example, when I enter "https://server.tld/playtool", I want to access the root of the play application. 
However, this is not working:

1. All assets are missing, because play generates their path as "/assets/*"
2. Although I can access the root of the application, other routes do not work, as they do not use the sub-uri: E.g. they refer to "server.tld/page" instead of "server.tld/playtool/page"

Here's my Apache Config for that host:

```
    <IfModule mod_proxy.c>
            ProxyPreserveHost on
            ProxyRequests Off
            <Proxy *>
                   Order deny,allow
                    Allow from all
            </Proxy>
            ProxyPass /playtool http://127.0.0.1:9000 retry=0
            ProxyPassReverse /playtool http://127.0.0.1:9000 retry=0
    </IfModule>
```

And here's the part of the play app regarding proxying/subUri

```
   application.baseUrl="https://server.tld"
   XForwardedSupport=127.0.0.1
   XForwardedProto=https
   XForwardedSupport=127.0.0.1
   http.path="/playtool"
```

Does anyone know what to do? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few points that may help.

I am still to find a way to generate the assets under relative URL, but one can set-up the absolute URL in such a way, that allows the Apache server to redirect the calls.

If your page is under `/playtool`, then you can change your play application configuration to point all assets to `/play/assets` instead of simply `/assets`. This way you can identify the assets per application and make sure that you redirect only the assets you need.

```
GET   /play/assets/*file     controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
```

This will allow you to do a redirect to those assets, like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/play/assets/(.*)$ https://server.tld/playtool/play/assets/$1 [R]
```

About your other problem - the links not working. This is easy to fix. You just need to have no absolute links (not starting with `/`) and have to have the base HTML tag defined. See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp for more information on the tag.

You could have the following then:

```
<base href="/playtool/">
```

Hope that this helps. I myself am not really satisfied with the assets redirect solution, so if you have already found out a better way to deal with that, please let me know.

EDIT:

You could instead of a redirect you another proxy for everything under `/play`. Something like this:

```
<Location /play>
    ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:9000/play
    ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:9000/play
</Location>
```

EDIT 2:

I finally managed to do it only with one proxy, without changing the assets' location.

Here is the proxy config on the Apache side:

```
<LocationMatch ^\/playtool\/?(.*)$>
    ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:9000/playtool/$1
    ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:9000/playtool/$1
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</LocationMatch>
```

Then on the Play side you would need to add the `play.http.context`, to setup your application context.

```
play.http.context="/playtool/"
```

Of course you would also need to configure the base HTML tag.